# Why won't date_based.archive_month in Django 1.3 work to show my blog posts?

Tags: django, blogs, archive

I'm just trying to list my blog posts for a certain month in a certain year, but none of my posts are showing. When I type in the correct url: 2011/nov, no posts show up and I have Nov. 2011 posts saved in my admin.

Also, for some reason, my css file isn't being taken into account.  When I go to the url, 2011/nov, I just get html with no styling and none of my posts.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
#models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique = True)
    body = models.TextField()
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

#urls.py
info_dict = {
    'queryset': Post.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'published',
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/$',
    date_based.archive_month,
    dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/archive.html',)),

#blog/archive.html
<link href="../static/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
.
.
.
{% for post in post_list %}
<h3 class="title"><a href="{% url single_post slug=post.slug %}">{{post.title}}</a>    
</h3>                        
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The CSS is not showing because you define it relatively to be `../static/style.css`. When the address is `/2011/jan` the browser tries to get the css from `/2011/static/style.css`. Fix: Set the path to be absolute: `/static/style.css`.
2. You should be looping through object called `object_list` instead of `post_list`.

   `{% for post in object_list %}`

Comment: thanks! It's working now, but how come I have to refer to it as object_list? I tried setting 'template_object_name':'post_list', but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The context variable that holds the post is called **object_list** not **post_list** so you should have:

```
{% for post in object_list %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/?from=olddocs#django-views-generic-date-based-archive-month

Your css file should be:

and if you are developing locally you need to set up the development server to server your media for you:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#using-django-contrib-staticfiles

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what pastylegs wrote above, you should also change this line

```
published = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

to this:

```
published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In Python, [named arguments are only evaluated once](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values). This means that the default `published` value is the time your server last compiled the `models.py` file. Django offers a solution to this: setting the parameter `auto_now_add=True`, makes django use the actual current time for the field, *when it's first created*. Similarly, setting `auto_now=True` makes django set the current time for the field *whenever it's saved*.